Pivot on multiple columns in snowflake
I have following table in snowflake table
ID     | NAME | QTY | LAYER
5026767  AB    25    1
5026767  XY    25    3
5026767  QE    50    2
5027016  TI    100   1
5027038  PP    30    1
5027038  CC    30    3
5027038  DD    40    2

What I want to aggregate NAME and QTY pivoted on LAYER. Such like following the output
ID      | '1' | '2' | '3' | NAME_1 | NAME_2 | NAME_3
5026767  25    25    50    AB       XY       QE  
5027016  100   Null  Null  TI       Null     Null
5027038  30    30    40    PP       CC       DD

I have tried with pivot but there are only aggregation available related to number not for char. Is there something I am missing?

if you want just one name, then min/max are the way to go..
with cte_data(id,name,qty,layer) as (
    select * from values
    ('5026767','AB', 25 ,   1),
    ('5026767','XY', 25 ,   3),
    ('5026767','QE', 50 ,   2),
    ('5027016','TI', 100,   1),
    ('5027038','PP', 30 ,   1),
    ('5027038','CC', 30 ,   3),
    ('5027038','DD', 40 ,   2)
)
select id
    ,sum(iff(layer=1,qty,null)) as "1"
    ,sum(iff(layer=2,qty,null)) as "2"
    ,sum(iff(layer=3,qty,null)) as "3"
    ,max(iff(layer=1,name,null)) as name_1
    ,max(iff(layer=2,name,null)) as name_2
    ,max(iff(layer=3,name,null)) as name_3
from cte_data



Thank you for your answer. Is there any dynamic way to do that if the number of layers got more than 3?

well you can use Snowflake Scripting to build the SQL, sure.
